# Php Rewrite text file content

Tags: php

I have basic php knowledge.  I have a text file that I need to rewrite the content of - so text file name stays the same but content changes.  How do I do that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you use the exec command.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results. [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<?php
$cont = "newcontentofyourfile";
$var=fopen("yourfile.txt","w");
fwrite($var, $cont);
fclose($var);
?>
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks.  I tried clicking the checkmark, said to try again in 5.